# What is "find-grained" image?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

What does exactly and precisely the term "fine-grained" mean in image segmentation? 
For example, undeniably, the picture below is a fine-grained image:

[image]

But is it correct to call below picture as a fine-grained image?

[image]

or

[image]

I think it means a picture with details. In my idea, by accepting this definition, every picture out there can be called "fine-grained".
Could anybody explain as precisely as possible what exactly a "fine-grained" image is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have encountered an example of the kind of use of "fine grained" that the question is about, could you please quote the source verbatim? All I get by googling is about fine-grained image classification, which means: fine-grained classification of images.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the Google results I find:

- [FGComp2013](https://sites.google.com/site/fgcomp2013/) which states:

> This challenge will target fine-grained classification, i.e. classification among categories which are are both visually and semantically very similar. This is a very difficult regime which is even challenging for humans without careful training, and is critical for establishing a more detailed understanding of the visual world.

- [The Stanford Dogs Dataset](http://vision.stanford.edu/aditya86/ImageNetDogs/) has its primary reference which states:

> First, being a fine-grained categorization problem,
>   there is little inter-class variation. For example the basset
>   hound and bloodhound share very similar facial characteristics
>   but differ significantly in their color, while the
>   Japanese spaniel and papillion share very similar color but
>   greatly differ in their facial characteristics.

So the upshot is that "fine-grained" means that the classes that are trying to be distinguished between are visually very similar.

In terms of a single image, it means that it is hard to see the differences across the entire image.  In that case, your top image is fine-grained. The dog and bird images are not.  Though if you zoomed into the hair of the dog or the feathers of the bird, I expect they would be.

Comment: Now I am completely confused because literately, "fine-grained" means an image with high detailed image like the first one in the question. what about the image of a dog? is it a fine-grained? or even the bird? all of them can be called "fine-grained". in term of "classification", the definition you provided is OK but what about a single image?

Comment: @David : Updated answer for single image.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But, what are differences between "fine-grained" images and "rich-texture" images?

Comment: That's not a term I've had much to do with, but it appears to mean "images with more happening in it than I really want".  For example, a building that we want to extract the outline of has ivy growing on the outside to give it more unpredictable texture (and lots more edges) than I want.